# How can I speed up a query with about 26 temp Tables

Tags: sql-server

I have a query, that creates 26 single Row temp tables. It then does an inner join linking them all based on a date. Each is a set of 3 or 4  aggregates. It creates a 110 columns Month End report.

When i run most of the query to create the temp tables, i get times around 1-30 seconds except for 2 of them that take about 10 - 15 min. Those 2 are aggregates of aggregates.

In my bench marking if I run 1 at a time and take max times, the whole thing takes about 40 min. However when I run them all at once they take minimum of 55 min.

Originally this query was 26 Sub queries and took several hours. I got it down to 55 min by switching to temp tables, but I really feel like I should be able to get it less.

Other information : the main 2 tables/views being used are around 50MM records with indexes that seems fairly good.

Pseudo Code:

```
Insert Avg, Sum, Count, Avg
into #temp1
Insert Avg, Sum, Count, Avg
into #tempN
.....n^26
Select * 
from #temp1 t1
join #tempN tN
on t1.MonEnd = tN.MonEnd
...N^26
```

Comment: For both MySQL and SQL server?

Comment: not sure if inserting in only one temp table adding an id column will help. instead of 26 joins, you will have a group by, won't you?

Comment: @Mackan Sorry, I should have tagged it SQL-Server only. (I didn't think it would matter)

Comment: @Horaciux The final select takes under a second after all the tables are made, it also performs some additional calculations (Non-aggregates)

Comment: To get some help, you'll probably have to include the query plan, statistics io output and table + index structures (at least for tables causing most of the io)

Comment: You say each temp table has one row.   Are you guaranteed that MonEnd is the same in all 26 tables?

Comment: @DavidDubois Yes, it is hard coded as a variable. 
    Select '20150531' 'MonEnd'

Comment: Focus on making the individual queries faster, maybe pre-aggregate or store running totals, get them down to seconds rather thAn minutes and you can do whatever else you like

Comment: @EdElliott yeah, I am working that angle too, whomever build this database put EVERYTHING in varchar! so everything needs converts/casts which isn't helping, thanks!

Comment: If all of the temp tables are one row, you don't need an inner join with a condition.   A crossjoin will return the same result.   Don't know if it will be any faster though.  I'd be inclined to try a single table that gets updated 26 times.   It's only one row, so you wouldn't need any WHERE condition in the updates.

Comment: btw, this being a month-end report, does it get run everyday, or is only generated once a month?  Does it need real-time data, or does it look at a previous month's data that is no longer expected to change?  Maybe you could pre-populate it at night.

Comment: @TabAlleman Thanks for the reply, it only get run on the 1st of every month. I am most likely going to put it into a SSRS report that runs early in the morning before its needed. Even if it takes an hour or 2.

I guess it comes down to just making the individual queries faster. Thanks everyone!

Comment: You say everything has to be cast/converted.  Are there cases where the same data is being converted multiple times?

Comment: @DavidDubois definitely, I was thinking of making some temp tables to cross walk the most common fields, for example all the dates are withing a 31 day period, so it wouldn't be to hard. I just don't know if the extra join every time would be faster then a million converts. Let me try it